# Code Formatting: Dealing with long invocations, operations, and boolean logic

Tags: java, javascript, format

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I'm curious as to best practice when formatting long lines of code.

**How Do we format each if they run too long**

> Note that this isn't about proper code below, just about how we format each type of run on statement.

*Say we have a long conditional operator in javascript/jquery*

```
var tablesToHide = $('table').length > 1 ? $('table') : $($('.nav > li[class="active"] > a').attr('href'));
tablesToHide.hide();
```

*Say we have a long conditional in java with null checks*

```
if(person.firstName != null && person.firstName.length() > 32 && person.firstName.length() < 5 && person.lastName != null &&  person.lastName.length() > 32 && person.lastName.length() < 5){//ridiculous operation}
```

*Say we have a long operation*

```
long worldVsUnitedStates = (worldDuckCount + worldCatCount + worldTugBoatCount)/(unitedStatesTugBoatCount + unitedStatesDuckCount + unitedStatesCatCount)
```

*A long method call like with Guava operations*

```
final Iterable<AccountingDocument> documentList = Iterables.filter(resultRecord.getAccountingDocuments(), AccountingDocument.class);
```

Large method parameters like in logging statements

```
logger.entering("UserAccountingAdministrationController", "createNewUserAccountingDocument", new Object[] { userAccountingForm, result, model });
```

Large method parameters due to using FindBugs and throws declaration

```
public void saveAccountingFormWithValues( @Nullable FooA firstValue, @Nonnull FooB secondValue, @Nullable FooC thirdValue, @Nullable FooD fourthValue) throws DataAccessException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a recommendation in the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) that lines of code shouldn't be longer then 80 characters *"since they’re not handled well by many terminals and
tools"*...obviously, this no longer holds true, however, that shouldn't mean we shouldn't strive for readability.

Even with LCD's and high res screens, not every one will use the same font size (one of my developers uses 14-16 pt fonts because of their eyes), so you should aim to for readability and make the statements easy to understand.

Group logical elements together where possible, particularly in things like `if` statements and complex calculations...

A lot will come down to the individual statement (also remember, not all tabs are equal), but...

I'd personally use something like...

```
if(person.firstName != null && 
   person.firstName.length() > 32 && 
   person.firstName.length() < 5 && 
   person.lastName != null &&  
   person.lastName.length() > 32 && 
   person.lastName.length() < 5) {...}
```

and

```
long worldVsUnitedStates = (worldDuckCount + 
                            worldCatCount +
                            worldTugBoatCount) /
                           (unitedStatesTugBoatCount + 
                            unitedStatesDuckCount + 
                            unitedStatesCatCount)
```

and

```
final Iterable<AccountingDocument> documentList = Iterables.filter(
    resultRecord.getAccountingDocuments(), 
    AccountingDocument.class);
```

IMHO

Comment: Now you format them very similar to how I would. But, I always find myself second guessing and asking myself if it's really readable to other developers. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: For every rule there is an exception.

Comment: FYI: The Java Coding Conventions link provided above also provides guidelines for splitting long lines.

Comment: @CoryKendall Yeah, I thought it would, should read it in more details ;P